# echo HTML statement containing a JSON object

Tags: php, html, escaping, echo

How can I echo this HTML statement in PHP?

```
<area id="6" class="seat" title="Seat: B3" coords="170,469,170,432,179,427,202,427,210,433,210,469"     shape="poly" data-maphilight='{"strokeWidth": 0, "stroke": true, "alwaysOn":true}'>
```

Answer (score 0):

use \ before " in your statement

like :-

```
<?php echo "<area id=\"6\"> </area> ?>
```

it will allow you to use " in your statement without any error.

Answer (score 0):

You should encode your object into JSON string using [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) first and then just echo it as an attribute.

Here you go.

```php
<?php
$json_string = json_encode($your_object);

echo '<area id="6" class="seat" title="Seat: B3" coords="170,469,170,432,179,427,202,427,210,433,210,469" shape="poly" data-maphilight=\''. $json_string. '\'>';
```